# Angular2 + karma + protractor - run specific e2e test case

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, karma-runner

What command can I use to start specific e2e test case from test suite?

If this is not possible - running specific test suite may be some workaround.

I use Jasmine, Karma and Protractor. I start my tests with command

```
npm run e2e
```

which is defined in `package.json`

```
"e2e": "protractor protractor.config.js"
```

I can redefine this task (or create new one)

```
"e2e-s": "protractor protractor.config.js --specs ./app/dashboard/e2e-spec.js"
```

But I'd like to perform this from command line.

Comment: Do you mean how to run a single spec?  `protractor config.js --specs /path/to/spec`

Comment: @Gunderson but I run tests with command `npm run e2e` - where can I put the path ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can [propagate arguments to the npm script](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3494) via the `--`:

```
npm run e2e -- --specs path/to/spec
```

<sub>Make sure you have the latest `npm` installed.</sub>

---

You can also focus tests with `fdescribe`/`ddescribe` in Jasmine and `describe.only` in Mocha.