# Is there a way to run a specific spec, i.e. one test file, from the command line when using npm e2e?

Tags: node.js, npm, e2e-testing

I am trying to run an e2e command but only choose one of the files listed in the spec option. I have tried using

```
npm run e2e /path/to/file
npm run e2e --grep"filename"
npm run e2e --spec /path/to/file
```

In all cases, all tests are run or errors are thrown.
I have to be able to do this from the command line as I cannot change the config file itself.
There are answers relating to `ng` commands, which also seems to be an issue for people, but very little on `npm`!

Am I missing something simple or is this not possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `e2e` script do? It could literally be anything :)

Comment: Just had a look at the package.json and it says e2e is set to run: ''' "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run emulate\" \"ng e2e --configuration=chrome --webdriver-update=false\"" ''''

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I guess the question has changed a bit now so youre under no obligation to reply but thanks for the tip to looking into at that. Any more advice would be more than welcome!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 + karma + protractor - run specific e2e test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829449/angular2-karma-protractor-run-specific-e2e-test-case)